# How and where to set weights in case of imbalanced cost sensitive learning in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, model-evaluations, weighted-data, imbalance

I confront with a binary classification machine learning task which is both slightly imbalanced and cost sensitive. I wonder what (and where in the modeling pipeline, say, in sklearn) is the best way to take all these considerations into account.

Class proportionality: positive: 0.25% negative: 0.75%. This could be addressed with `sklearn.utils.class_weigh.compute_class_weight`:

```
class_weights = compute_class_weight(y=y, class_weight='balanced')
```

OK, but this is only for rebalancing proportionalty, I should take misclassification cost into consideration as well. Let's say that this is 10* larger in case of false negatives than false positives, so I guess that I should still increase the weights in `class_weights` accordingly by upweighting positives further by 10, right?

But there is another point in the pipeline where I could take care of this, namely in the evaluation metrics with F-beta for example with upweighted recall (F2, for instance). Does it have the same effect? Should I pick one method (F-beta for evaluation OR upweighting classes) or both of them simultaneously?.

Additionally, in case I upweight my classes with `compute_class_weight()`, I assume that no further class distribution should be taken into consideration downstream (so when I use `RandomForestClassifier()`, `class_weight` hyperparameter shouldn't be `='balanced'`, again, because this would further distort the weights proportionality that is already set before. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

> *Additionally, in case I upweight my classes with compute_class_weight(), I assume that no further class distribution should be taken into consideration downstream (so when I use RandomForestClassifier(), class_weight hyperparameter shouldn't be ='balanced', again, because this would further distort the weights proportionality that is already set before. Is this correct?*

**The util function is just a utility** that will return you the dictionary for class weight.

The place where you will use this dictionary is the *class_weight parm of the Model e.g. RandomForest*.

So, you will have to pass the return of the Util to the model.

Better, just keep the parameter value = *"balanced"* Or any specific value *e.g. [{1:1}, {2:5}, {3:1}, {4:1}]*

> *OK, but this is only for rebalancing proportionalty, I should take misclassification cost into consideration as well. Let's say that this is 10* larger in case of false negatives than false positives, so I guess that I should still increase the weights in class_weights accordingly by upweighting positives further by 10, right?*

**Just using the Util** and getting the dict of weight will not have any effect. Action will happen only when the Model uses the class_weight parameter.

The Model will add corresponding weight to the misclassification cost of the minority class. Low-level design detail changes with Model *e.g. Neural network, Decision tree*.

> *But there is another point in the pipeline where I could take care of this, namely in the evaluation metrics with F-beta for example with upweighted recall (F2, for instance). Does it have the same effect? Should I pick one method (F-beta for evaluation OR upweighting classes) or both of them simultaneously?*

**Change in Scoring technique will be needed** because whatever be the Class weights, the counts are still unbalanced e.g. 100:1. So, 90 correct of the majority will make the overall accuracy ~90 which can be deceiving.